Change directory & get git command outputs in a file using Makefile
I need to run "git log" command from Makefile and store the logs in another file. This I need to do for 2 different paths i.e. for 2 different repos
I have tried this in Makefile-
  git_logs:
    cd $(PATH1)    
    @git log -1 --stat > path1_logs.txt    
    cd $(PATH2)    
    @git log -1 --stat > path2_logs.txt    
    @echo "Git logs stored"  

It seems however that cd doesn't change directory & only echoes "cd $(PATH1).  How can I modify the cd command? Or is there some other easier way to do what I expect?

Make launches a separate shell per line. You have to use oneliners: cd ... && git log ....

You could use git -C DIR CMD without changing the current directory: git -C $(PATH1) log -1 --stat > $(PATH1)/path1_logs.txt.
